# adding multiple model records a form within a form - Collecting Tabular Input yii

Tags: yii

I am kind of lost. I am following this [Collecting Tabular Input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table). I have a product form, within the product form I have a attribute form, like colors/sizes. I am having trouble understanding this tutorial because of the loop in controller. So I get that it checks the number of records and loop it but what if there's no record. It seems like the tutorial is saying to create a new Model. Yes, of course. But how can you possibly loop it in view if there's no record and telling it to create a new one. Maybe I am not understanding this correctly.

I am just looking to add 3 records, blank or filled. No js to add additional record. Trying to understand this first.

controller:

```
public function getProdAttr($id) {
        $items = array();
        if (isset($_POST['ProductAttribute']) ) {
            $items = ProductAttribute::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('product_id',$id));
            if($items!==null){
            foreach ($_POST['ProductAttribute'] as $item) {
                    $items[] = ProductAttribute::model()->findByPk($item['product_attribute_id']);
                }
            }
                else $items[] = new ProductAttribute();
        }
        return $items;
    }

public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    $attributes=$this->getProdAttr($id);
    if(isset($_POST['ProductAttribute']))
    {
        $valid=true;
        foreach($attributes as $i=>$attribute)
        {
            if(isset($_POST['ProductAttribute'][$i]))
            $attribute->attributes=$_POST['ProductAttribute'][$i];
            $valid=$attribute->validate() && $valid;
            }
            if($valid)
                $attributes->save();
            }
    //stuff from product model
}
```

view:

```
//stuff for product model form

<div class="form"> 
    <?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>
    <table>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th></tr>
    <?php foreach($attributes as $i=>$attribute): ?> //lost here, what if there's no records?
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($attribute,"[$i]name"); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextArea($attribute,"[$i]description"); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($attribute,"[$i]cost"); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you solve this problem? I've got the same

Comment: I didn't use this. To add another model in the form, I used `aftersave()` method in the model and added the other model's info. From the form, I used `setState` and then retrieve it later on.